# Exit hook working both on Bash and ZSH

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

I need to create a script that basically sets some env variables, starts a subshell and, when exited, run some additional code, as a hook. It needs to work both on Bash and ZSH, and I'm aware that maybe I should maintain two different scripts.

The reason I need it is to create some kind of *bootstrap* script. For example, I create a file named *Bootstrap.sh* with two functions, `start` and `exit`, and when I run the script, `start` should be called and a new subshell is activated. When the subshell exits, `exit`, is finally called. For example:

```
# Bootstrap.sh
start() {
    export CUSTOM_VAR="hello world"
}

exit() {
    echo "byebye"
}
```

> $ bootstrap
>   $ # finds "Bootstrap.sh", loads it and then calls "start" function
>   (myenv) $ echo $CUSTOM_VAR
>   hello world
>   (myenv) $ exit
>   byebye  # this is my exit hook
>   $ # back to "normal" shell

I'm testing hooks with [this script](https://gist.github.com/lucassmagal/6226951), based on a suggestion to improve Python's [virtualenv](https://gist.github.com/datagrok/2199506). In this file I tried to use trap (a) and TRAPEXIT(b), none of those worked:

```
# (a), the "bash way", I think
my_hook() {
    echo "exit hook called"
}
trap my_hook EXIT
exec "${@:-$SHELL}"
```

```
# (b), as explained in ZSH documentation
# http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Functions.html
TRAPEXIT() {
    echo "exit hook called"
}
exec "${@:-$SHELL}"
```

So, how can I do it (in both ZSH and Bash, if possible)?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about shell of [Unix/Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @LucM, I don't understand. Isn't it a technical question?

Comment: It only means that your question doesn't fit here because it's not about programming. IMHO, your question should be asked on another site of StackExchange network : [Unix&Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @LucM: Oh no! It's about programming (the shell, it is), and recasting the question as "does exec count as exit for the purposes of a trap" it's not even obvious what the answer should be. Though it could have been asked at the other site.

Comment: Hem, I'd say this is pretty much programming, as it is writing a script in shell as opposed to some random twiddling on the command line.

Comment: I retracted my close vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the 'exec' at the end. This (obviously) doesn't count as exit. The substituted process, of course, doesn't inherit the exit handler of the shell.

Solution: Replace

```
exec "${@:-$SHELL}"
```

by

```
"${@:-$SHELL}"
```

PS: I said *obviously*, because I never wondered if it would (count as EXIT, I mean). I had to try it out, but  it stands to reason, that exec has nothing to do with exit. The process only exits when the '{@:-$SHELL}' terminates.

Answer (score 5):

As per ZSH man page, ZSH also supports the `trap` builtin; that is,

```
trap 'any code here' EXIT
```

works on ZSH as well, and ofc you can have a function name as the code string.

If you need to wrap the exec, the following should work on both bash and zsh

```
function exec {
    echo "Execcing"
    builtin exec "$@"
}
```